# confirmation email with a custom user model not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, email-confirmation

im having a problem in creating a confirmation email that leads to a view and set up the account.is_active to True
things that keep in mind ,i have a custom user model that abstracts from the User model
the token generator works fine ,i get the email i click the link ,it says that the account is activated but nothing actually is happening i think the problem is in the activate view

my models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email",max_length=60, unique=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True)

date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined",auto_now_add=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login",auto_now=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','phone']


objects = MyAccountManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
    
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin
def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True
```

tokens.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six

class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, account, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(account.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(account.is_active)
        )
account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

view.py

```
    #active view==========================================
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, Account.DoesNotExist):
        account = None
    if account is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(account, token):
        account.is_active = True
        account.save()
        login(request, account, backend="users.backends.AccountAuthBackend")
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

i used to work with the same way with the default django User but now when i changed to my custom user model and working with rest framework api this happened

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens?

Comment: the link takes me to the view it says email activated but in the admin panel the user account still set to is_active = False
it should be True if the link was correct

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Can you please check if you tested correct user?

Comment: what do you mean by correct user?

Comment: try to debug this code with pdb/print and see if it is getting correct `account`.

Comment: yes i do get the correct link on the provided email on registration
the problem is that the activate function is not changing the is_active status on the user model   everything stays the same even after the activation function completed successfully

Comment: did you place the urls in correct order?

Comment: yes the urls is in a correct order